# Using EdgeHTML instead of MSHTML

Tags: c++, mfc, com, microsoft-edge, mshtml

We have developed a Windows Desktop HTML/XSL editing application, written in C++ using MFC/ATL/COM technologies, relying heavily on MSHTML's IHTML* COM interfaces, like IHTMLElementPtr, IHTMLDocumentPtr, IWebBrowser2, and so on, making it easy for an end user to build a website.

We are now looking at using EdgeHTML instead of MSHTML in our application. I have been searching for examples of how to create a simple editing application using EdgeHTML written in C++ to get started with finding out what's needed and how EdgeHTML works as an HTML editor. I have been unsuccessful in finding anything useful, ie, a full sample application.

We have to use C++ as our programming language.

Can anyone please help us in how to get started, ie, explain, provide or suggest where I can find a useable, functioning sample application as described above?

All we need is something to get started with.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766249/using-webview-edgehtml-in-delphi-c-builder