# Is it possible to use Microsoft Edge (Chromium engine) in Delphi like TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, microsoft-edge, chromium

Microsoft announce new browser [Edge](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/) browser based on chromium engine.  Just wondering if it is possible embed the browser like TWebBrowser into a VCL application?

Comment: You mean [Chromium for Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi)? It's not Edge, but it is Chromium.

Comment: No. I mean Microsoft Edge (using Chrome engine).

Comment: Although a bit unrelated, you can also use EdgeHTML until WebView2 is available - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766249/using-webview-edgehtml-in-delphi-c-builder

Answer (score 5):

At present, Microsoft developer is developing a Microsoft Edge WebView2 control, it enables you to host web content in your application using Microsoft Edge (Chromium) as the rendering engine. More detail information, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2).

You could feedback your request at the bottom of [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2).

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Hope someone able to roll out a delphi VCL sample for it.