# Using Chromium Edge WebView2 in Delphi or C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, microsoft-edge, c++builder, chromium

Now that the Microsoft Chromium Edge is final, is it possible to use it in Delphi or C++ Builder?

As I understand it is based on a `WebView2` component.

Is there a component such as `TWebView2` or will Embarcadero provide one? Is there an example how to host WebView2 in Delphi / C++ Builder?

Is it enough to install the latest Edge version so the app can utilize it?

There was an example for the older version - EdgeHTML - here:
[Using WebView (EdgeHTML) in Delphi / C++ Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766249/using-webview-edgehtml-in-delphi-c-builder)

**Update:** the question above has been updated with the new version of Edge in 10.4+ release of RAD Studio which uses WebView2 now. So see the above question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebView2 in your application.

> Is there an example how to host WebView2 in Delphi / C++ Builder?

For samples of how to host WebView2 in your application using C++, please refer to [Webview2 Samples](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples).

> Is it enough to install the latest Edge version so the app can utilize it?

You will also need to install [Webview2 SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2) as well as Microsoft Edge(Chromium).

For other details about using Webview2, please refer to [Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2#supported-platforms).

Notes: Webview2 is still in preview phase, breaking changes could happen in the feature releases.