# TEdgeBrowser and CoreWebView2 printing in C++ Builder

Tags: microsoft-edge, c++builder, tedgebrowser

CoreWebView2 exposes methods like [ShowPrintUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.showprintui?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1466-prerelease#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2-showprintui(microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2printdialogkind)) which I'd like to utilize.

However, it seems that RAD Studio, even in the latest version 11.3 has hpp files from a pretty old build - 1.0.1054.31 from 2021, at least that is shown in the GetIt Package Manager. This has not been updated for a very long time and Embarcadero seems to be very slow in updating this.

It appears that the `ShowPrintUI` requires at least 1.0.1518.46 version of the SDK.

Is there a way to add those headers to the current C++ Builder installation, or at least the relevant part for using `CoreWebView2.ShowPrintUI()` or `CoreWebView2.PrintAsync()` and how specifically?

I already know about the workaround to execute JavaScript like `window.print()` which I do not want to use as a solution as it doesn't pop up a new window but shows the user interface inside of the TEdgeBrowser window.

I am guessing that, if newer headers would be available the usage would be as easy as:

`EdgeBrowser1->DefaultInterface->ShowPrintUI();`

Per support reply by Embarcadero representative, they plan to update headers in the future major release, but I'd like to avoid the wait as I also have to use this in an older version of C++ Builder.

Comment: There are corresponding examples for these two APIs in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/print?tabs=win32cpp#the-showprintui-method-to-open-a-print-dialog), have you referred to them?

Comment: For the examples to work I have to have updated headers. The question was about updating headers, not about examples how to use ShowPrintUI.

Comment: If this is the case, you can contact the WebView2 team and send your feedback, as mentioned in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/contact#submit-feature-requests-or-bugs-in-the-webview2feedback-repo).

Comment: @XudongPeng My question is about C++ Builder headers, have you read that?

Comment: It looks like I misunderstood your question, are you referring to precompiled header files?

Comment: I am talking about `WebView2.hpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by updating the `WebView2.pas` and `WebView2.hpp`, based on this answer:

[WebView2 (TEdgeBrowser) updated Delphi interface (e.g. ICoreWebView2Controller2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676662/webview2-tedgebrowser-updated-delphi-interface-e-g-icorewebview2controller2)

One obstacle I encountered was that some interfaces which were generated by `tlibimp.exe` were duplicates, already defined in other include files.

Some duplicates were:

```
IDataObject = interface;
IEnumFORMATETC = interface;
IAdviseSink = interface;
IPersist = interface;
IPersistStream = interface;
IMoniker = interface;
IBindCtx = interface;
IRunningObjectTable = interface;
IEnumMoniker = interface;
IEnumString = interface;
IEnumSTATDATA = interface;
```

Also, some other symbols needed things like `{$EXTERNALSYM GUID}` or `{$EXTERNALSYM tagRECT}` and a few others.

Additionally, some variable names were conflicting with C++ such as:

```
function AddHostObjectToScript(name: PWideChar; const object: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
```

Which I had to redefine to:

```
function AddHostObjectToScript(name: PWideChar; const object_: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
```

Most of these changes I was able to figure out how to properly remove or redefine by comparing the generated `WebView2.pas` and `WebView2.hpp` to the original one included with RAD Studio including some of the above redefinitions and external symbols.

After a few hours of doing this, I ended up with working new interfaces and now I can utilize all the recent interfaces released in the meantime since Embarcadero last update (which was beta version of Edge Chromium interface) and the most recent one.

It would be really nice if Embarcadero would include updated interface, which I have also requested in their QC portal.