# Controlling headers and footers when printing using TEdgeBrowser component

Tags: html, delphi, printing, microsoft-edge, tedgebrowser

The `TWebBrowser` component has been [replaced by the `TEdgeBrowser`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_TEdgeBrowser_Component_and_Changes_to_the_TWebBrowser_Component).  My goal is to customize the text in the header and footer sections of a printed HTML page when the user prints using the `TEdgeBrowser` component.

I was able to accomplish this when using the `TWebBrowser` component by writing code to temporarily set the Internet Explorer registry keys at the time of printing ("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup": 'header' and 'footer' keys).  However, these same keys don't seem to exist for the Edge browser.  The closest I found was the ['PrintHeaderFooter' key](https://admx.help/?Category=EdgeChromium&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Edge::PrintHeaderFooter), which enables/disables the headers and footers.

Is there a way to modify the header and footer content in my Delphi application when printing using the new `TEdgeBrowser` component?

Comment: There'a discussion here: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/6770-tip-for-creating-pdf-files-from-html-image/

Comment: @UliGerhardt Thanks.  The discussion doesn't really come to a resolution or explain the solution in the images presented.

Comment: In the linked discussion, "der schöne Günther" is using html code and CSS inside the html document to create a header and footer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document for possible approaches to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When printing yourself using the `Print` method of the WebView2 control, you can specify your own strings to use instead of document title and document uri in the header and footer:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PrintSettings: ICoreWebView2PrintSettings;
begin
  (EdgeBrowser1.EnvironmentInterface as ICoreWebView2Environment6).CreatePrintSettings(PrintSettings);

  PrintSettings.Set_ShouldPrintHeaderAndFooter(true.ToInteger);
  PrintSettings.Set_HeaderTitle('New Header text');
  PrintSettings.Set_FooterUri('New Footer text');

  (EdgeBrowser1.DefaultInterface as ICoreWebView2_16).Print(PrintSettings, nil);
end;
```

You can also control more stuff via `PrintSettings` like selecting the printer to use by name, choosing paper size and page orientation, etc.

---

In order to get access to the types `ICoreWebView2PrintSettings`, `ICoreWebView2Environment6` and `ICoreWebView2_16` follow the steps in [Marcodor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72405170/101087) at [WebView2 (TEdgeBrowser) updated Delphi interface (e.g. ICoreWebView2Controller2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676662/webview2-tedgebrowser-updated-delphi-interface-e-g-icorewebview2controller2).

---

- [Microsoft documentation of Print method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.printasync)

Comment: Thanks.  I've attempted to implement your solution.  The headers and footers are shown as expected, but the content of the print appears blank even though there is content loaded in my `EdgeBrowser`.

Comment: Hm, strange, it works for me. I have tested with several different websites. Can you share the website you use for testing or a html file that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Figured it out.  It was an issue unrelated to your code. @NineBerry Thanks.