# How to install WebBrowser2 component (Edge Chromium) on Delphi XE8?

Tags: delphi, webview2

Can i install the WebBrowser2 component (edge chromium) on Delphi XE8?
I tried to import WebView2.tlb from
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2/1.0.774.44
I get error (error accessing the ole register)

---

I install from
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/
MicrosoftEdgeWebView2RuntimeInstallerX86.exe
In Delphi - Import component- search "edge" and install "Elevation_service.exe" this does not have a visual component in Delphi.

---

Who can help me step by step to have a webbrowser2 (Edge Chromium) visual component with Delphi XE8?

Comment: You may have more luck embedding the "real" Chromium with [CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi).

Comment: Delphi 10.4.2 includes TEdgeBrowser component.

Comment: The webview2 controle is not a regular ActiveX/com control and as such does not have a type library of that kind. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766249/using-webview-edgehtml-in-delphi-c-builder    You can try to build the needed libraies yourself as stated in the SO reference, but moving to the latest Delphi version will save you a hell of a job.

Comment: I want to use a web component to view pdf files passed via TStream variable. WebBrowser uses internet explorer library and doesn't do this, to open a pdf it wants a physical file not a variable. I have read that WebBrowser2 with (chromiun) accepts a pdf also as Tstream. I can't use Delphi 10.4 which has WebBrowser2 (chromium) component because it doesn't have D WinInet.dll which I need for my SOAP functions already developed with Delphi XE8.
I tried CEF4Delphi with Delphi XE8, and I didn't like it.