# Feasible to get WebView2 working in old Delphi versions and Lazarus?

Tags: delphi, lazarus, webview2

I have taken a look at these URLs:

check if runtime installed
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution

some sample code assuming newer Delphi
[Using WebView (EdgeHTML) in Delphi / C++ Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766249/using-webview-edgehtml-in-delphi-c-builder)

some sample code assuming newer Delphi
[WebView2 (TEdgeBrowser) updated Delphi interface (e.g. ICoreWebView2Controller2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676662/webview2-tedgebrowser-updated-delphi-interface-e-g-icorewebview2controller2)

Yet even those seem to assume a newer Delphi version than I use (XE4) ... and preferably I would like Lazarus support as well. At the same time I really love being able to use "newest available patched system browser" which is why I am not jumping on https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi albeit it may end up being the final solution.

Is there anyone else who has begun the undertaking of implementing webview2 on older versions or is this simply impractical due to type libraries not being importable etc? (i.e. major headache in converting, implementing and testing everything, furthermore on old Delphi versions)

Comment: I looked at the Vcl.Edge.pas and it contain nearly 2 thousands line of code. The WebView2 type library import is another one thousand lines of code (But should be generated you Delphi). It will probably be faster, easier and less expensive to upgrade your Delphi to the current one (10.4.2 at time of writing this comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently published [WebView4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/WebView4Delphi) at GitHub with an MIT license.

WebView4Delphi uses the WebView2 runtime to embed Chromium based browsers in Delphi and Lazarus applications.

It was developed in Delphi 11 but it also works with Delphi XE3.

Comment: Fantastic job! Thank you so much from every old-style Delphi programmer. Works like a charm!